# Azure SAML Group Claim Filtering

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure for SSO to an application. Azure syncs to our AD, so I am using SAMAccountName with Group Filtering to only pass certain group where the group name contains certain strings. However, I can't seem to figure out how to match *multiple* strings.

For example, I can get it to match groups that have the string "test" but I need to pass groups that match either "test" and "user". So in this case both testgroup and usergroup would be passed. Is this possible?

My current settings are:

**Attribute to Match:** SAMAccountName

**Match With:** contains

**String:** test,user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Microsoft doesn’t support matching groups with `multiple strings` at a time. It’s possible to filter one at a time to verify desired results.

You can configure filters to be applied to the ****group's display** name** or **SAMAccountName** attribute.

**Contains:** Matches any location in the selected attribute.

Filtering String should be either **test** or **user.** In that way, you can pass either **testgroup** or **usergroup** at one time.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am matching one string at a time at the moment. Hopefully in the future Ms will introduce multiple string matches.